# Function to apply member function to set

Tags: set, ssas, mdx

Is there an mdx function that takes a set as an argument and a member function as a separate argument and returns a set with that function applies to the members?

I have a set of selected dates,  and want to return a set with the same dates less 1 year,  so need to use Parallelperiod on each member.

Comment: I added an answer which works - please use it as I'll delete it soon - it has been marked down even though it is an answer ?! strange. I'll try to add alternatives (there are probably a few - Lag function comes to mind) although we really need to see the structure of your Date dimension - can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks! Apologies I accidentally marked it down instead of up!

Answer (score 2):

This approach seems to work ok:

```
WITH 
  SET [fewDays] AS 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070121]
    : 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070127] 
  SET [theDates] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [fewDays] AS s
     ,{ParallelPeriod
      (
        [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]
       ,1
       ,s.CurrentMember
      )}
    ) 
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,[theDates] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

[image]

I think this is prettier and it avoids Generate so may be faster:

```
WITH 
  SET [fewDays] AS 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070121]
    : 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070127] 
  MEMBER [Measures].[cntMembers] AS 
    [fewDays].Count 
  SET [LastMemLastYear] AS 
    {
      ParallelPeriod
      (
        [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]
       ,1
       ,Tail([fewDays]).Item(0)
      )
    } 
  SET [theDates] AS 
      [LastMemLastYear].Item(0).Lag(
      [Measures].[cntMembers])
    : 
      [LastMemLastYear].Item(0) 
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,[theDates] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: Looks perfect.. Will try it when back in the office tomorrow.

Comment: Indeed. No need for generate here.